# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion - array appears to be a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm looking at the following section of code that is throwing the above error:

```
$rv = "'".str_replace("'", "''", str_replace(':', '\\x3a', str_replace('\\', '\\x5c', $value)))."'";
```

To make this a little easier to read, I broke out the above into discrete statements:

```
$sq = "'";
$dq = "''";
$sr1_value = str_replace(':', '\\x3a', $value);
$sr2_value = str_replace('\\', '\\x5c', $sr1_value);
$sr3_value = str_replace($sq, $dq, $sr2_value);
$sr4_value = $sq.$sr3_value.$sq;
$rv = $sr4_value;
```

The second to the last line causes the Array to string conversion error to appear.

I've tried other methods of concatenating that string (i.e. brackets, substr_replace) and I've even tried using implode on sr3_value, which throws the error that "argument must be an array".

I'm stumped, because it seems, initially, that the error is that sr3_value is an array, but passing it as an argument to implode() shows that it isn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

-John

Comment: I'd rather check `var_dump($value)`.

Comment: @raina77ow - An excellent point :D

Comment: If you could add the value of `$value` to your question it will be a lot easier to help - your script is [perfectly fine](http://codepad.org/7ye81nXS) :)

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: I used var_dump on a buffer to a file and got this: http://www.hytronix.com/~john/vardump.txt that is, $value dumped out the file referenced above.

Comment: It appears that sometimes it's actually an array, but usually a string.  What's the best way to catch that?

Comment: You can use `file_get_contents` instead of `file`, if I got your message correct. )

Comment: maybe do an is_array check before the str_replace so you can just ignore them, or you could convert them into a string if it is an array.